# 5 digit number $a6a41$ divisible by 9

Tags: number-theory

In the 5-digit number $a6a41$ each of the a's represent the same number. If the number is divisible by 9, what is the digit represented by $a$?

I first approached this by saying $$2a + 11$$ since it's divisible by 9. I got stuck because I didn't know what to equate it to. So I randomly said $2a + 11 = 27$ and then I got $ a = 8$ and indeed the number was divisble by 9. My question is, how do I know what to equate it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if $(2a + 11)$ is a multiple of $9$, then

$$(2a + 11) = 0\ (mod \ 9)$$

so $$(2a + 2) = 0\ (mod\ 9)$$

and since $(2a + 2)$ is even, it follows that

$$(a + 1) = 0\ (mod\ 9)$$

Comment: Can you explain the last step? Is it because if $2a+2$ is divisible by $9$ and even, it must be divisble by $18$, and therefor you can divide by $2$?

Comment: Can you please explain what you did in the fourth line of your solution?

Comment: If we know that $x$ is a multiple of 9, then $x/2$ is also a multiple of 9 iff $x$ is even, because odd values of $x$ result in fractional values. For any integer $a$, $(2a+2)$ has to be even.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I taught of that myself, but couldn't write it down clearer

Comment: But i mean when you changed 2a +11 to 2a + 2

Comment: @user108104 Oh, *that* fourth line :-) The numbers 2 and 11 are the same in [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) with a modulus of 9. In other words, if you subtract 9 from a multiple of 9, the result will be another multiple of 9. Similarly, on a clock face, the hands point in the same directions at 09:00 and 21:00 every day because $(9\ mod\ 12) = (21\ mod\ 12)$.

Comment: @user108104 As squeamish points out, the first step is subtracting 9 from both sides. $0 - 9 = 0$ in mod 9 arithmetic. The second step can be seen as dividing both sides by zero. $0 / 2 = 0$, remains true in any arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look a little more carefully at the divisibility rule you're applying.

> A number is divisible by 9 if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by 9

There is nothing overtly in here about equality, although there is an explanation with a type of equality I'll discuss in a second.

Bottom line is, no matter what digit you pick $a$ to be, as long as $2a+11$ is divisible by 9, that $a$ will work.

If you are learning modular arithmetic, then you really can find an equality. A number $n$ satisfies $n\equiv 0\pmod{9}$ iff 9 divides $n$.

So the rule you mentioned above can be rephrased as

> A number is equal to 0 mod 9 iff the sum of its digits is equal to 0 mod 9.

Solving $2a+11\equiv 0\pmod{9}$ for $a$ is not really much different than solving $2a+11=0$. You can say that $2a\equiv -11\pmod{9}$, and then you need to find an inverse for 2 (that us, a number to multiply it with that turns it into a 1. Module 9, it's easy to discover that $5$ does the trick. So, $a\equiv 5\cdot2a\equiv 5(-11)\equiv -55\pmod{9}$. To get $a$ to be a digit, we need to shift it by multiples of 9. As you can see, $-55\equiv -55+63\equiv 8\pmod{9}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, problems like this may have multiple solutions, so there may not be a unique $x$ in the equation $2a+11=x$. However, there are a few restrictions that apply:

- $a$ must not be negative, so $x\geq 11$;
- $a< 10$, so $x<31$.

This leaves only $a=18,27$ to try. Moreover:

- $2a$ is even and 11 is odd, so $x$ must be odd as well,

so 27 is the only possibility.